# Ubuntu Server 14.04 install error: can't umount /media

Tags: server, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 on an old dellcomputer, but as soon as I get past the initial menu, choosing to install Ubuntu Server, I get some console output and everything gets stuck on:

```
mount: mounting /dev/sda on /media failed: Invalid argument
umount: can't umount /media: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev/sdb on /media failed: Invalid argument
umount: can't umount /media: Invalid argument
```

Ubuntu Link: system installation

[Installation Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598110/ubuntu-server-14-04-2-install-error-cant-umount-media/628695#628695)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best would be disable any floppy diskette, any slave or other IDE devices from BIOS settings. Only enable the peripheral device setting and reboot the computer. It should be able to mount properly from the target location. Its easy and works for me .. :)